# Java Mail API: Callbacks

Tags: java, email, smtp, jakarta-mail

### Context:

I am working on a piece of Java code where I am reading mails from an array (which works fine). I was wondering if someone can help me with the callback in order to show a fancy message like `Your email was sent`.

### Questions:

> How do I implement this?
>
> Is there any way to get any Boolean type return value from `javax.mail` to check if the message was sent or not?
>
> Maybe I should create a pool? If yes, how do I do that? Is there any signal to kill the pool?

### Code:

```
// addressTo is the array.
Transport t = sesion.getTransport(this.beanMail.getProtocolo());
t.connect(this.beanMail.getUsuario(), this.beanMail.getPassword());
t.sendMessage(mensaje, addressTo);
t.close();
```

Answer (score -1):

Quoting from the ***[JavaMail API FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html)*** (in the context of tracking bounced messages):

> While there is an Internet standard for reporting such errors (the multipart/report MIME type, see **[RFC1892](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc1892)**), it is not widely implemented yet. **[RFC1211](http://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc1211)** discusses this problem in depth, including numerous examples.In Internet email, the existence of a particular mailbox or user name can only be determined by the ultimate server that would deliver the message. The message may pass through several relay servers (that are not able to detect the error) before reaching the end server. Typically, when the end server detects such an error, it will return a message indicating the reason for the failure to the sender of the original message. There are many Internet standards covering such Delivery Status Notifications but a large number of servers don't support these new standards, instead using ad hoc techniques for returning such failure messages. This makes it very difficult to correlate a "bounced" message with the original message that caused the problem. (Note that this problem is completely independent of JavaMail.)

### [Source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq-135477.html#bounce)